# Can we send email with attachment with on the fly data i.e file not being present locally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp

I have a requirement to send email attchment using SMTP and python, the code runs a DB query, i'm making a dataframe from the obtained data, now the that data needs to be send via email with attachment.
the question is should i have to store that dataframe as a file locally and send? or is there a way to send the dataframe as a file without storing?

requesting suggestions

Comment: You can always look into the `StringIO` - their purpose is to mimic the file.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. If you want more specific suggestions, see [ask] and [edit] your question and add your code as a [mcve] (as text, not screenshots). What exactly are you struggling with?